# Is there a possibility to allow different data types in an abstract constructor?

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class

**Long story short: Is there a possibility to allow different data types in an abstract constructor?**

**Detailed question:**
I want to define an abstract constructor which allows multiple data types:

```php
abstract class ValidationRule
{
  protected $ruleValue;
  protected $errorMessage;

  abstract public function __construct($ruleValue); // see here

  protected function setErrorMessage($text)
  {
    $this->errorMessage = $text;
  }
}
```

Extending classes now implement the abstract constructor.
I wanted the constructor to allow different data types (int, bool, string, ...).

```php
class MinCharacters extends ValidationRule
{
  public function __construct(int $ruleValue) // see here
  {
    $this->ruleValue = $ruleValue;
    $this->setErrorMessage("At least " . $this->ruleValue . " characters necessary.");
  }
}

class Required extends ValidationRule
{
  public function __construct(bool $ruleValue) // and here
  {
    $this->ruleValue = $ruleValue;
    $this->setErrorMessage("Field required.");
  }
}
```

When I instantiate an object, i get the following error. I know the issue, but want to know if there is any solution how to allow multiple data types in the constructor.

```php
$rule = new MinCharacters(5);
/*
Fatal error: Declaration of MinCharacters::__construct(int $ruleValue) 
must be compatible with ValidationRule::__construct($ruleValue) in 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on line 51
*/
```

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible as long as you use type hinting. However I don't see any benefit of defining a constructor as abstract, but the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no particular sense to define an abstract constructor.

The constructor of a class is already exempted from the usual method signature compatibility rules when a class is extended.

So you can either:

- define the constructor as a regular (non-abstract) method
- or omit its definition altogether

And in both cases the extended classes can define whatever constructors they want/need.

But by defining the method as **abstract**, you are saying "**a method of a compatible signature needs to be implemented when extending**", and thus making the "constructor exception" void.

Answer (score 1):

Just omit the constructor in your abstract class.